# Javascript Regex Wildcard

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this js code

```
$('a').each(function(){
   if($(this).css('background-image')=='url("http://www.example.com/img/icon/earn-point-435912.png")'){
       $(this).parent().remove();
   } 
});
```

I want to such that it return true if its match

```
http://www.example.com/img/icon/earn-point-**Wildcard**.png
```

The number **435912** is a wildcard.

How do I change my code to make it works. Thanks!

I tried the following but not working still

```
$('a').each(function(){
   if($(this).css('background-image')=='url("http://www.example.com/img/icon/earn-point-circles-.*.png")'){
       $(this).parent().remove();
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex operations have to be done with the JavaScript regex object. The regex you might want would look like this:

`^http://www.example.com/img/icon/earn-point-\\d+\.png$`

`\d+` is the wildcard for at least 1 digit, and the first backslash is escaped in the JavaScript string.

The regex makes sure it is an exact match without any other characters before or after the URL. For more flexibility, remove ^ and $ from the regex.

This is your code with that regex:

```
$('a').each(function(){
   if(
       RegExp("^http://www.example.com/img/icon/earn-point-\\d+\.png$").test($(this).css('background-image'))
   ){
       $(this).parent().remove();
   } 
});
```

Comment: Using a regex literal will do the same job but there will be a lot of escape sequences for characters in the URL such as forward slashes - making it time consuming to modify the script